# SSRS When uploading report owner name is wrong

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have SQL 2014 professional version 12.0.5000.0 with SSRS runing. eI have created a report in report builder 3.0 which works and runs find.

However when I go to create a subscription and run I get the user a1234 (as a example )  don't exist.

I looked there is no user with that name added to SSRS or in our domain.

my user name is ah1234 (as a example )

I looked in the subscription table and the owner is me ? However, the subscription is showing the owner as a1234?

I checked the report I uploaded it says the owner is a1234.

I'm thinking it might be a active directory issue but not sure.

Has anyone has see this before if so how can I fix the owner name of the subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how SSRS has corrupted the owner name but here is a trick (written on 2008 R2) to correct owner names (I use this when people leave & their Active Directory user id gets deleted leaving orphaned subs that will not run).

**Note that it updates the Microsoft-supplied subscriptions table, you may not wish to do that.**

First identify the SSRS owner id for the from-person & also that of the to-person (you may need to get the to-person to create a subscription first):

```
SELECT distinct [OwnerID], u.username 
  FROM [<ssrs-database>].[dbo].[Subscriptions] s 
  join [<ssrs-database>].[dbo].[Users] u on s.ownerid = u.userid
```

Now make a safe copy of the subscriptions list, e.g.:

```
SELECT * into temp.subscriptionscpy 
  FROM [<ssrs-database>].[dbo].[Subscriptions] s
```

Now make the change, e.g. (this one changes the owner of all relevant subs):

```
update [<ssrs-database>].[dbo].[Subscriptions] 
  set ownerid = 'DDD87598-8957-42C8-8DBC-A893E7174CB6'
  where ownerid = 'EBF0E483-69E6-4458-B171-BA28FFCCDF3F'
```

Now check the owner is as you want it.